# How do i change the INT value of a checkboxed sql-item in react?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

So my problem is that i have a database in mysql with different bikes which in my database are stored on different locations with the value FK_Location.

And i want to move these bikes between the FK_Locations by checking the bikes i want to move and then moving them by selecting from two locations in my dropdown (California and Texas).

Bikes1 are the bikes in location 1, bikes2 are the bikes in location 2.
The only thing that needs to change is the sql integer FK_Location of the bikes. If i manually change the value in my sql, the bikes changes location. The checkboxes also work; i just need a button that sends the data to my backend, alas changes the FK_Location from for example 1 to 2, but im not sure how to code it. Ive tried changing the state but thats only local.

```
export default class Locations extends Component {
render() {
bikes1 = [];
bikes2 = [];


              <p>1 - California</p>
              <List>
                {this.bikes1.map(bike1 => (
                  <List.Item key={bike1.BikeID}>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={bike1.checked} onChange={e => (bike1.checked = e.target.checked)} />{' '}
                    {bike1.BikeID} - {bike1.Brand}
                  </List.Item>
                ))}
              </List>

              <p>2 - Texas</p>
              <List>
                {this.bikes2.map(bike2 => (
                  <List.Item key={bike2.BikeID}>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={bike2.checked} onChange={e => (bike2.checked = e.target.checked)} />
                    {bike2.BikeID} - {bike2.Brand}
                  </List.Item>
                ))}
              </List>


            <select id="Location" value={this.FK_Location} onChange={e => 
        (this.FK_Location = e.target.value)}>
                <option value={1}>California</option>
                <option value={2}>Texas</option>
              </select>

 mounted() 
    locationService.getBikesLocation(FK_Location => {
      this.FK_Location = FK_Location;
    });
    locationService.getBikesLocation1(bikes1 => {
      for (let bike of bikes1) bike.checked = false;
      this.bikes1 = bikes1;
    });

    locationService.getBikesLocation2(bikes2 => {
      for (let bike of bikes2) bike.checked = false;
      this.bikes2 = bikes2;
    });
```

````
   class LocationService {
  getBikesLocation(success) {
    connection.query('select * from Bike', (error, results) => {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
      success(results);
    });
  }
  getBikesLocation1(success) {
    connection.query('select * from Bike where FK_Location = 1', (error, results) => {
      if (error) return console.error(error);

      success(results);
    });
  }
  getBikesLocation2(success) {
    connection.query('select * from Bike where FK_Location = 2', (error, results) => {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
      success(results);
    });
  }```










Could anyone try to make me any wiser here, or give an example?
````

Comment: React runs in the browser, node runs on the server. React code cannot run queries directly. To change database data from React, you have to use AJAX to send requests to the server: [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: @ChrisG Im using node aswell, and i can change database values in other parts of the app

Comment: React runs in the browser, node runs on the server. The fact that both is JS doesn't matter; it might as well be Dutch and Chinese. To call server-side (node) code from React code, you have to use AJAX/fetch().

Comment: @ChrisG Hm, i see. But this code changes the name of a customer in my database, so im kinda lost on this ```        <Card title="Edit Customer">
          <Form.Label>FirstName:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Input
            type="text"
            value={this.customer.FirstName}
            onChange={e => (this.customer.FirstName = e.target.value)}
          />

Comment: What database exactly are we talking about? A mySQL server running on the node machine?

Comment: @ChrisG i have an online phpmyadmin server which connects to node like this https://imgur.com/a/3P9J50w

Comment: Right. I'm unclear on what your setup is. The component in your question looks like it shouldn't compile at all. How is node serving your React app? Is `mounted()` part of that Component? Where is `locationService` coming from on the client?

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry for being so unclear, im very new at this: I've pasted the code to this site: https://justpaste.it/50759. The SendBikes1 and 2 functions currently serve no purpose.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? Are you using create-react-app? express?

Comment: @ChrisG We made a small project at school where the teacher gave us this to use as the fundament: https://gitlab.com/ntnu-idri1005/react-widgets by cloning with git, and now im making an app by myself with the same fundament

Comment: Oh, you're using electron! That explains it. Ok, forget everything I said. I guess the only thing you need is an `UPDATE` query. For instance `UPDATE Bike SET FK_Location = 2 WHERE id = 1` will change the first bike's location to 2.

Comment: @ChrisG Ah, yes i use electron! I didnt know that made a difference. Thank you for the guideline, so what im thinking now is i make that sql query as a function in services.js and then an if statement in locations.js which calls the funtcion if the bikes are checked. But how do i only move the checked bikes? By using a for loop with a length counter?